# After building a model based on under-sampled data, what data should be used for model validation?

Tags: r

I am building a decision tree model with rpart function. Due to imbalanced data, I had to undersample my data. I first split my data into training and validation at 70:30 ratio, and did undersampling on the training data set. Now I have the model built. I wanted to confirm if this is correct to run the predict and confusion matrix on the validation data. There is no need to undersample the validation data.

```
 Model_1 <- rpart(Tag~.,
            data = data_downsample ,
            method = "class",
            control=rpart.control(
            minsplit=20,
            cp=0.002,
            maxdepth = 2
            )
          )
Model_1 
rpart.plot(Model_1 )
summary(Model_1 )
pred <- predict(Model_1 , validation, type = "class")
perf <- table(validation$Tag, pred, dnn=c("Actual", "Predicted"))
perf
```

validation is the 30% of the base population.
Thank you.